# Cannot get Cmake to bake rpath into executable if prefix used

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake setup that makes an executable and a shared library I'm using a non-standard install prefix and want to bake the RPATH into the executable. Reading a bunch of previous questions as well as the kitware wiki leads me to this:

Top CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.14 )
project( cmakeprogram VERSION 1.0 )

add_executable( program program.cxx )

set( CMAKE_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" )
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" )
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE )
add_subdirectory( lib )
target_include_directories( auxlib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRECT_SOURCE_DIR}" )
target_link_libraries( program PUBLIC auxlib )

install( TARGETS program DESTINATION . )
```

Library:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.14 )
project( auxlib )

set( CMAKE_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" )
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" )
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE )
add_library( auxlib SHARED
             aux.cxx aux.h )
target_include_directories( auxlib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRECT_SOURCE_DIR}" )
install( TARGETS auxlib DESTINATION lib )
```

Running ldd on the program (SuSe linux if it matters) in the build & isntall location respectively gives:

```
build
        libauxlib.so => /stuff/build-publiclib/lib/libauxlib.so (0x00002ad64984c000)
prefix
        libauxlib.so => not found
```

Yes, I have read https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling but 1. that seems to be about cmake 2.whatever and 2. still doesn't get me the correct solution.

Comment: It is not so obvious from the article, but variables `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` and `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH` should be set **before** creation of the target (`add_executable( program program.cxx )` in your code). As for `CMAKE_RPATH`, this variable has no special meaning for CMake.

Comment: That was it. Thanks. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so obvious from the article, but variables `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` and `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH` should be set **before** creation of the target:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.14 )
project( cmakeprogram VERSION 1.0 )

# All further targets on installation will have given RPATH.
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" )

add_executable( program program.cxx )

add_subdirectory( lib )
```

---

Funny thing that even documentation of [CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH.html) variable is misleading:

> This is used to initialize the target property `INSTALL_RPATH` for all targets.

But description of the [INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INSTALL_RPATH.html) correctly specifies the situation:

> This property is initialized by the value of the variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` **if it is set when a target is created**.

Actually, in CMake initialization of the most target properties from variables follows the clause bolded above.